# How to install gscam in ROS hydro?

Tags: ros-hydro, gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How can i install gscam for webcam images in ROS Hydro in ubuntu 12.04? I tried to install it using synaptic manager in ubuntu. But when i run "roscd gscam" in terminal, it says that no command found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78206/how-to-install-gscam-in-ros-hydro-?/) by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No command founds suggests that you have not setup your ROS envionment and roscd cannot be found. Make sure that you have sourced the setup.bash which is appropriate.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosqueries](https://answers.ros.org/users/6415/rosqueries/) on 2013-09-11**:
Although roscd is unable to found gscam but gscam node starts working from the terminal. The problem i facing is that everytime, i have to set GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace from terminal and then run rosrun gscam gscam. I have already kept that line in .bash but still its not working and i have to  write that first in terminal. How can i get rid of it...how can i start gscam from roslaunch?